# Literal datetimes as yyyy-mm-dd throw an exception

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a database configured with Spanish settings, when I use literal datetimes as yyyy-mm-dd I get a varchar out of range conversion error.

```
select convert(datetime, '2014-11-19')
```

returns

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 3 La conversión del tipo de datos
> varchar en datetime produjo un valor fuera de intervalo.

I have to write those datetimes in spanish format. This works fine:

```
select convert(datetime, '2014-11-19')
```

Shouldn't I be able use both, the Spanish and the yyyy-mm-dd format ?. I don't want to use the Spanish format because a new costumer could use the same database with different regional settings.

I don't have any problem with date literals, only with datetimes. This works fine in both Spanish and yyyy-mm-dd format.

```
select convert(date, '2014-11-19'), 
       convert(date, '19-11-2014')
```

Thank you.

Comment: Using a datetime2 format works with european dates - and if you really need it in datetime, you can double convert it i.e select convert(datetime,(convert(datetime2, '2014-11-19') ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yyyy-MM-dd` is not unambiguous in SQL Server. Use either `yyyyMMdd` or `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn`. If you aren't American SQL Server (foolishly) reads `yyyy-MM-dd` as `yyyy-dd-MM` for the old data date and time data types. Based on your error, you aren't American and hence the error.

*Note: `yyyy-MM-dd` is unambiguous for the newer date and time data types. Microsoft fixed that "feature".*

Alternatively, you can provide a style code to `CONVERT` to specify the format. In this case, that would be style 23: `CONVERT(date time,'2014-11-19',23)`

Comment: Adding that the `yyyy-MM-dd` literal is not ambiguous in the case of `date`; `SELECT CONVERT(date, '2014-11-19') ;` returns the proper value regardless of the `DATEFORMAT` setting.

Comment: That why I mention in the *old* data types @DanGuzman .

Comment: Thanks. I will use yyyymmdd.

Comment: @Larnu, I did not see that in your initial answer.

Answer (score 0):

`datetime` is more-or-less a legacy type, and this is one of its quirk. The way it treats date literals in `yyyy-MM-dd` form is affected by the [DATEFORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) parameter.

The real solution is to *not* use date literals in the first place. Use parameters with the appropriate type instead, in this case `date`.
When you do have to use a date literal, use `yyyyMMdd`. Avoid using `datetime`, using either `date` or `datetime2` instead.